# jquery ui datepicker range between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please show me how to enable range in jquery ui datepicker, I want to determine range in the format: from 2012-12-10 to 2012-12-20 etc (yy-mm-dd, already specified). All other dates should not be available.

Appreciate the help I can get, cheers!

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), there is even a [demo](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) on how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
function setInterval(){
$(function() {
    $( "#startDate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#endDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#endDate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#startDate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
}
```

where

```
startDate  
endDate
```

are the two input fields of datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
jQuery("#date").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function() {
        return {
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            minDate: '2012-12-10',
            maxDate: '2012-12-20',
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `maxDate` and `minDate` options when creating.

[Link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

Code:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: value1, maxDate: value2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, example:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2012, 12, 10), maxDate: new Date(2012, 12, 20) });
});
```

I just wanted to add the following links which you might find useful:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/