# How to restrict jqueryui date range?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have two date-pickers `#from` and `#to`, as usual, now what I need to do is make sure that the date range selected between the two is always within 3months of each other. So basically, on selecting one of the pickers, I need to set minDate/maxDate option for the other one relative to the selected date, But I don't know what would be the best way to find these relative dates. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ui datepicker range between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530800/jquery-ui-datepicker-range-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you could do it like this:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/jFafx/)
Both ways are valid, i suppose.

.js

```
$("#startDatePicker").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText,dateObj){            
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        dateObject.setMonth(dateObj.currentMonth+3);
        $("#endDatePicker").datepicker( "option", "maxDate",dateObject);  
    }
});
$("#endDatePicker").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText,dateObj){
            var dateObject = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            dateObject.setMonth(dateObj.currentMonth-3);
            $("#startDatePicker").datepicker( "option", "minDate",dateObject);
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunu/2BQyd/).The range between the days is set to 3 days.you can edit based on ur requirement

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#startDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function (date) {
        if ($('#endDatePicker').val() == "") {

            var selectedDate = new Date(date);
            var secsPerDay = 86400000;
            var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + 2 * secsPerDay);
            alert(endDate);
            $("#endDatePicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            $("#endDatePicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", endDate);
        }
    }

});

$("#endDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    onSelect: function (date) {
        if ($('#startDatePicker').val() == "") {
            var selectedDate = new Date(date);
            var secsPerDay = 86400000;
            var startDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() - 5 * secsPerDay);

            $("#startDatePicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", startDate);
            $("#startDatePicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    }

});
});
```

and HTML

```
<p>Start Date:
<input type="text" id="startDatePicker"/>
</p>
<p>End Date:
    <input type="text" id="endDatePicker"/>
</p>
```