# date input with ability to choose range or one date

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, calendar, daterangepicker

I need to implement date range input with calendar. there is daterangepicker.com for example but my client want it to be able to choose one date without clicking two times. like it should be possible to click on one date once or to click on two dates to choose date range. I use just html, css, js with jquery.

I didn't find how to implement it with daterangepicker

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530800/jquery-ui-datepicker-range-between-two-dates